# If sequence of finite Blaschke Products $(B_n)_{n\in N}$ converges uniformly to $B$ then $\frac{B_n(z)}{z^m}$ converges uniformly to $\frac{B}{z^m}$

Tags: uniform-convergence, maximum-principle, hardy-spaces, blaschke-products

I am having problem with showing that if sequence of finite Blaschke Products

$$B_n=z^m\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{|z_k|}{z_k}\frac{z_k - z}{1 - \overline{z}_k z}$$

where $(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{D}$ and $|z_n| \rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, converges uniformly to $B$ on compact subsets of open unit disk, then function sequence $(\frac{B_n(z)}{z^m})$ converges uniformly to $\frac{B}{z^m}$ on compact subsets of open unit disk.

I got stuck to this statement. Hint for this is that Maximum principle should be used but don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Fix $r \in (0,1)$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then for $n \ge n_0$ you have $|B_n(z) -B(z)| < \varepsilon$ ($|z| \le r$).  Thus, $|B_n(z)/z^m-B(z)/z^m| < \varepsilon /r^m$ ($|z|=r$). Now apply the maximum principle.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thank you for the help, @Gerd !